# Substituion of property on README file on play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'd like the contents of the README file of my Play! application to be configured with some property substitution. For example:

> This application was built with ${sbt.version}

Where `sbt.version` was read from the `build.properties` file. When running `play dist`, the application would be packaged with a README file with the actual `sbt.version`. What's the easiest, most conventional way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new task in sbt and then redefine the dist task to use your new task.  http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html has information on both of these.  You'll likely want to read through some of the other sbt documentation, however.